# inaccurate height value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to make a slide show, and the changing height of that block is calculated by jquery. When a user clicks different tabs, related contents slide down, and the height of that block changes.(because the slides cover another block of things, I have to set it a absolute one) The problem is that the height changes one step later when I click the tabs.I mean, when I click the first one, it doesn't move. When clicking the second, the height of the first one is setted..Here is the code:

```js
$('.home_zb_w635_ss li').unbind("click").click(function() {
  var bodyPaddingL = ($(document.body).width() - 1010) / 2;
  var $this = $(this);
  var id = $this.attr("data-code");
  if ($this.hasClass("home_zb_iconclick")) {
    $this.removeClass("home_zb_iconclick");
    $(".home_around_sj").hide();
    $(".home_around").slideUp();
    $('.main').height(310);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("home_zb_iconclick").siblings().removeClass("home_zb_iconclick");
    $("[data-id].home_around_box").slideUp();
    $("[data-id=" + id + "].home_around_box").slideDown();
    $(".home_around").slideDown();
    $(".home_around_sj").show().css({
      left: $this.offset().left - bodyPaddingL + 32,
      top: 149
    });
    $('.main').height(310 + $('.main_965').height() + 31)
  }
});
```

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
hr,
p,
blockquote,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ul,
ol,
li,
pre,
fieldset,
lengend,
button,
input,
textarea,
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font: 12px/1 Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, "\5b8b\4f53", sans-serif
}
h1 {
  font-size: 18px
}
h2 {
  font-size: 16px
}
h3 {
  font-size: 14px
}
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: 100%
}
address,
cite,
dfn,
em,
var {
  font-style: normal
}
code,
kbd,
pre,
samp,
tt {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace
}
small {
  font-size: 12px
}
ul,
ol {
  list-style: none
}
a {
  text-decoration: none
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}
abbr[title],
acronym[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  cursor: help
}
q:before,
q:after {
  content: ''
}
legend {
  color: #000
}
fieldset,
img {
  border: 0
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-size: 100%
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}
hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll
}
.focus-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 466px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1010px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.banner {
  min-width: 1010px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 466px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 200px;
}
.main {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 310px;
}
.main-1010 {
  width: 1010px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #0FF;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
.qr_right li {
  width: 86px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
}
.home_around {
  background: #FFC;
  padding-bottom: 31px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.home_around_box {
  padding: 5px 25px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
  line-height: 45px;
}
.home_around_sj {
  background: #FFC;
  width: 18px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}
.main_left {
  margin-top: 18px;
  width: 383px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.botton_bu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  background: #F30;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:50px;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  color: #dedede;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  margin-top: 30px;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s8pc" style="width:100%; text-align:center; position:relative;">


  <div class="focus-wrap">
    <div class="banner">banner</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="main-1010">
      <div class="main-po" style="position:absolute; top:-45px; left:0; width:1010px; z-index:100;">
        <div class="qr" style="background-color:#f0f0f0; width:100%; height:158px; z-index:100;">

          <div class="qr_right">click tabs to slide up contents
            <ul class="home_zb_w635_ss">
              <li data-code="airport"><a href="javascript:void(0)">tab1</a>
              </li>
              <li data-code="subway"><a href="javascript:void(0)">tab2</a>
              </li>
              <li data-code="business"><a href="javascript:void(0)">tab3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="home_around" style="display: none;">
          <div class="home_around_sj" style="display: block; left: 680px; top: 149px;"></div>
          <div class="main_965" data-id="ulall">
            <div class="home_around_box" data-id="airport" style="display: none;">
              <a pick="true" lt="1" mt="001" style="text-decoration: none" data-code="0" title="火车站">content</a>
            </div>
            <div class="home_around_box" data-id="subway" style="display: none;">
              <a pick="true" lt="1" mt="001" style="text-decoration: none" data-code="0" title="地铁13号线">content</a>
              <br />
              <a pick="true" lt="1" mt="001" style="text-decoration: none" data-code="1" title="地铁1号线">content</a>
            </div>
            <div class="home_around_box" data-id="business" style="display: none;">
              <a pick="true" lt="1" mt="001" style="text-decoration: none" data-code="0" title="大市场/批发市场">content</a>
              <br />
              <a pick="true" lt="1" mt="001" style="text-decoration: none" data-code="1" title="购物广场">content</a>
              <br />
              <a pick="true" lt="1" mt="001" style="text-decoration: none" data-code="2" title="商业街/步行街">content</a>
              <br />
              <a title="" lt="1" mt="001" style="text-decoration: none" class="" data-code="493">content</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_left">HERE
          <br />WOULD
          <br />BE
          <br />TEXT</div>
        <div class="main_left">HERE
          <br />WOULD
          <br />BE
          <br />TEXT</div>
        <div class="botton_bu">These block of red things will cover up the footer part when sliding</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```

I really can't find the problem, I hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: Can you please set up a fiddle an include your markup...

Comment: @prodigitalson  the website is in our internal network...so, i can't give you the link...it'll be published a few days later.

Comment: @prodigitalson oh,i see what you mean, i'll build an example page now.

Comment: does it gives any errors when the function is called? or when the pages loads? try printing the variables that causes the function go wrong and check if it goes all as expected